# Saving data in HTML format and displaying in HTML format MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Not sure if this can be posted here, but I have a textarea where I allow the user to add a long description, but I dont know how to save it in an HTML format so that it can be displayed the same way.

I type it out in my textarea as below, but it saves it in "one line" and also displays it this way, not picking up that there are "paragraphs(i.e. pushing enter twice)"

PS: I am saving it in my DB, so it s not that I dont know how to save the data, its just to save it in a way that when displayed when pulling the data, that it will show it the way I typed it and not all in one line.

Example:

```
Hi there

This is a description including "enter" character, or even bullets

•   Slow turnaround times
•   Branches unable to assist with certain queries
•   Letters/emails are too complicated to understand
```

I have read some saying you must use a CKEditor, but is this really necessary? And will it save the data in a way that will be displayed in the same format? Can this not be done with the normal textarea? I am trying to keep it as simple as possible.

This is what I am currently using:

```
<textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="5" cols="3" placeholder="Challenge Description" type="text" name="challengedescription" id="challengedescription" value="@Model.ChallengeDescription" rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Challenge Description" data-content="Provide context to the business problem or opportunity that you have identified for innovation. Including statistics and facts are great to contextualise your innovation opportunity! Define the problem statement which speaks to the root of the problem or opportunity. Ensure that there is a clear call to action. E.g. what, by when and the desired outcome."></textarea>
```

And I am trying to display like this :

```
<p>
    @Html.Raw(Model.ChallengeDescription)
</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make use of C# and save it in the backend somewhere, and pass it in via the `ViewBag` when you load the page?

Comment: I am saving it in a SQL DB, but when I pull the data then it displays everything in one line, instead of the way it was typed and saved. This is the problem.

Comment: What it in `<p stype="white-space: pre-line">` element (browsers collapse whitespace by default unless you style it)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but wont the problem actually lie in how it is saved in the DB ? I tried doing the change above in my <p> tag and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :)

So I left my `<textarea>` exactly as it was, however, after submitting to be saved, I just used the following in my `controller`:

```
 model.ChallengeDescription = model.ChallengeDescription.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

All sorted.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: Completely unnecessary if you use `white-space: pre-line;`